# C select always detects a socket readable

Tags: c, sockets, select

I looked for an answered on quite similar topic, but I have not find a good answer (I think).

First my code :

```
fd_set readset;
int result;

while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(sock_client, &readset);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readset);
    result = select(sock_client + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (result > 0) {
        if (FD_ISSET(sock_client, &readset)) {
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
             read(server_socket, buffer, 5000);
            printf("%s", buffer);
        } 

        if (FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readset)) {
            memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            read(fileno(stdin), msg, 5000);
            printf("%s", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (error in the read() corrected):**

```
// socket client
sock_client = do_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

// socket server
server_socket = do_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// server connexion
do_connect(server_socket, 
    (struct sockaddr *) & addr_sock_host, sizeof(addr_sock_host));

fd_set readset;
int result;

while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(sock_client, &readset);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readset);
    result = select(sock_client + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (result > 0) {
        if (FD_ISSET(sock_client, &readset)) {
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            int size = read(sock_client, buffer, 5000);
            printf("size : %i\n", size);
        } 

        if (FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readset)) {
            memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            read(fileno(stdin), msg, 5000);
            printf("%s", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it :

```
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
size : -1
```

... infinitely

**END OF EDIT**

Actually, select returns always 1 because sock_client is always in readset whereas there is nothing to read on it. Over more, my FD_SET are in the infinite loop. That's why I don't understand how it's possible that sock_client be detected as readable (always) ?

I hope you will understand my problem and I apologize if the question has already been asked.

Thanks

Comment: When select says that sock_client is readable, what happens when you read from it? Specifically, what does the read() call return?

Comment: When you get to EOF, the socket is always readable, and returns `0` when you read from it. You need to close the socket then and stop selecting on it.

Comment: Select()ing readable actually means: "a read() will not block" (in most cases, etc) And: after select()ing readable, you should do the read(), and use its return value.

Comment: Isn't this enough for a valid answer? Combine the *reading won't block* semantics of `select()` with the hint this might be caused by EOF, I'd say this *is* an answer ...

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem is that the program is blocked on the read. I mean that the program is waiting to get something to read from "sock_client", so I don't have any call return from read().

Comment: Why are you selecting on `sock_client` but reading from `server_socket`? Looks like a simple typo. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You definitely right, I'm sorry ! Shame on me, I have this in front of me for 2 hours and I didn't see it. However, now I am receiving the call return from read() which is -1. But the problem remains, sock_client is always detected as readable indefinitely.

Comment: Please post the exact code  and the new behaviour in the question proper (not as comments). Please leave the original code there so that the comments trail remains valid. Add the new code below the current.

Comment: Is your `sock_client` actually connected? I'm guessing your `do_socket` only creates (and perhaps binds) the socket. But where is the connect?

Comment: I think the connexion is OK, the connexion happens with 'do_connect'. It worked well before I add a select to detect messages from server in fact.

Comment: Well, what does read() returning -1 *mean*? Why don't you check errno?

Comment: You're right, I haven't good automatism yet. I get this with perror() : Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: So you're still, after all this, reading from the wrong socket, or else you've never accepted a client in the first place. I don't see that anywhere. NB Don't think that error checking is something you add later when it's all working. You'll never get it working without the error checking.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I am surely doing something wrong ;)

Comment: But there is no `do_connect` shown that uses `sock_client`. And that's exactly what the perror told you - it's not connected.

Comment: Correct ! I just realized that I hadn't understood well the connect() function ... And it worked before by chance. Thank you all again for your time, I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `memset(),` and you cannot convince me that reading from the listening socket blocks. The real problem here is that you are:

- reading from the wrong socket FD, and
- completely ignoring the value returned by `read()`.

You need to:

1. Store it in a value.
2. Compare it to -1, and if so call `perror()` or one of its friends immediately, and close the socket.
3. Otherwise, compare it to zero, and if so clos the socket.
4. Otherwise, use the positive value that must remain as the length of the incoming data? That's why you don't need the `memset()`.